# read value validation

Tags: command-line, input, stdin, read

Is there a way to validate or confirm that the user wrote what it meant to write in `read`?

- For example, the user meant to write "Hello world!" but mistakenly wrote "Hello world@".
- This is very similar to contact-form validation of an email / phone field.

Is there a way to prompt the user with something like "Please retype the input", in read?

I found no such option in `man read`.

---

Note: The input is a password so I don't want to print or compare it with an already existing string.

Comment: If you want to confirm _every_ time, just read twice, perhaps with a `printf` in between to tell them you are doing so

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, this data is sensitive so I avoid printing. I've edited the question. I assume that `read` twice doesn't make sure the second input is identical to the first.

Comment: It does if you read to different variables and compare them — and then either exit or loop back (with a message?) if they don't match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `bash` shell, you can always do

```
FOO=a
BAR=b
prompt="Please enter value twice for validation"
while [[ "$FOO" != "$BAR" ]]; do
    echo -e $prompt
    read -s -p "Enter value: " FOO
    read -s -p "Retype to validate: " BAR
    prompt="\nUups, please try again"
done
unset -v BAR
# do whatever you need to do with FOO
unset -v FOO
```

`read` options used:

- `-s` Silent mode. If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed.
- `-p prompt` Display prompt on standard error, without a trailing newline, before attempting to read any input.

Comment: What's `read -p`? I didn't find a `man` entry.

Comment: @Arcticooling Try `man bash` :-)

Comment: @Arcticooling In `bash`, the manual for individual built-in commands is also available using e.g. `help read`.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a function for that.

With `zsh` or `bash`:

```
blind_read_and_confirm() {
  # args: <prompt> <variable-name>
  local _confirm_
  until
    printf >&2 %s "$1"
    IFS= read -rs "${2-REPLY}" || return
    printf >&2 "\n%*s" "${#1}" 'and again: '
    IFS= read -rs _confirm_ || return
    eval '[ "${'"${2-REPLY}"'}" = "$_confirm_" ]'
  do
    printf >&2 "\nEntries differ, please try again.\n"
  done
  printf '\n'
}
```

To be used for instance as

```
blind_read_and_confirm "Please choose a password: " password || exit

printf 'You entered a %s character password.\n' "${#password}"
```

Note that without the `IFS=` and `-r`, if the user entered `" \/ery secret "`, `"/ery secret"` would be stored in `$password`.

Comment: I suppose in Bash or ksh we could do without the `eval` with a nameref

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes, though only ksh93 does real namerefs. For instance, with bash that still wouldn't allow `blink_read_and_confirm prompt _confirm_`. In `bash`, that's just cosmetic sugar over `eval`, so you might as well use `${!2}` (like `${(P)2}` in `zsh`)